Signal processing roadmap
I'm new to this field please can anyone tell me what is the correct roadmap to learn signal processing?
I've already searched on YouTube but no answers

Signal processing applies to any field that works with signals. So: what field(s) are you interested in? Audio? Image? Radar? Biomedical? Seismology? Communication? Astronomy? Financial Engineering? Robotics? ...
